# Custom Post Type Specific Post Template

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, single

I created a Custom Post Type, and here's the entire code:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function wrestler_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Wrestlers', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Wrestler', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Wrestler Profiles', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Profile', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => 'wrestler',
        'with_front'          => true,
        'pages'               => false,
        'feeds'               => false,
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'wrestler_profiles', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Profiles of WWE Superstars & Divas', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => url + '/icon.png',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
        'query_var'           => 'wrestler',
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'wrestler_profiles', $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'wrestler_register', 0 );
```

Now, I have also added single-wrestler.php to my theme's root, but every time I'm viewing the page it lands on "Single.php".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason wordpress don't honor [Template_Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). The best way to get around this problem is to "force" wordpress to use the custom single.php template that you created. To accomplish that, add the following function underneath your CPT.

```
   /* Information Posts Template selection - a single.php just for our wrestler_profiles */
function pietergoosen_info_template_include( $original_template ) {
    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['wrestler_profiles'] ) && false == $wp->query_vars['wrestler_profiles']  ) {
        return get_template_directory() . '/single-wrestler.php';
    } else {
        return $original_template;
    }
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'pietergoosen_info_template_include' );
```

Just remember, if you are using your CPT in a child theme or in a plugin, change `get_template_directory()` accordingly

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the game, but I thought it was worth noting for future reference that your custom post type is called "wrestler_profiles" and your template is "single-wrestler.php."  Your template should be named "single-wrestler_profiles.php" to match your custom post type name.  As per the template hierarchy (http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), to override the single template for a custom post type the name should be "single-$posttype.php"

If you were adding the custom post type via a plugin, Pieter's excellent solution is the only one I have found that works.